# Uso do bindingNavigator

Tags: c#, datagridview

Preencho um `dataGridView` via SQL e preenchendo um `dataTable`.

Gostaria de associar um `bindingNavigator` a este `dataGridView`.

Não estou conseguindo. Segue o código.

```
string arquivo = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString() + "Sistema_de_provas.accdb";
OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection();
cn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" + arquivo + ";Jet OLEDB:Database Password=; Persist Security Info=False;";
cn.Open();

OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand();
com.Connection = cn;
com.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM PROVAS";

OleDbDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader(); 
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(dr);
dataGridView2.DataSource = dt;
bindingNavigator1.BindingSource = dt;
cn.Close();
```

Está com problema nesta linha:

```
bindingNavigator1.BindingSource = dt;
```

Ou seja, depois do sinal de igual não aceita `dt`. Qual o erro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na propriedade [`BindingNavigator.BindingSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.bindingnavigator.bindingsource(v=vs.110).aspx), informe um [`BindingSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
// ...
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();

dt.Load(dr);
bs.DataSource = dt;

dataGridView2.DataSource = bs;
bindingNavigator1.BindingSource = bs;

// ....
```

Comment: Perfeito. Muito obrigado stderr.